# How can I synchronize custom fields in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

How can I synchronize Custom Fields in Wordpress in functions.php file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You should really check out this plugin: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com I have been using it for about 10 sites and it's really great! Since the latest update it's posible to export your custom fields to a PHP file which you can include your functions.php

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But this plugin was complicated my work a little.

I have try this: in functions.php file
add_action('update_post_meta', 'my_function');
In my_function function I get from the database current value of the custom field and update it in another places.
It works when I click on the main "Update" button. If I just click on Cutsom Field's "Update" button, it doesn't work. It works in this way: the system calls my_function first, then its function is called, I need vice versa. Priority of add_action doesn't work.